# Can I get the command history in a screen while something is running in it?

Tags: gnu-screen

I've got a screen with a critical process running in it. I can't kill it, but I need to know the command that was used to start it. Can anyone offer a solution?

Answer (score 3):

If your long running critical process is running in [screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> will start a new screen.

You can then find the command line for the process with

```
ps -efww
```

which should show you the complete command line.

If it's not running in screen you can try <kbd>Ctrlz</kbd> followed by [`bg`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bg) to suspend the command the put it in the background.

Comment: Or just log in again ;-)